# SEO: Best Title for the Car Repair company (Toyota, Nissan, Mazda, Honda)

Tags: seo, title

What would be the best Title for the home page for the following situation?

Company name: SuperCompany

Professional area: car repair service, specialize in 4 brands: Toyota, Nissan, Mazda, Honda.

Our current variant: “SuperCompany – Best car repair service | Toyota | Nissan | Mazda | Honda"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuperCompany - Toyota, Honda, Mazda and Nissan car repair service. Location, state.
Doesn't have too many characters, states location, brands and what you do.

Comment: Could be ok, but at least 83 characters in the title, this will always be truncated, or changed by Google.

Comment: I think the location info can be omitted, since the company isn't bound to any specific location (they are international company), and so we have nice and short Title: "SuperCompany - Toyota, Honda, Mazda and Nissan car repair service"

Comment: Ah ok, i must have misunderstood you. But are you gonna have one global site for all international locations? Or a landing page depending on country? In that case, than stating location on landing pages would be a good idea, but this is just my opinion.

Comment: That's a good advice, since the website has separate landing page per each locale. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do one homepage probably "SuperCompany - Japanese Cars Repair", then I would create one landing page each brand.

Comment: So what would be Title for the landing page? Say, for Toyota?

Comment: as @Baptiste Placé touched upon, I would put "Toyota Car Repair CitywhereSuperCompanyIs - Supercompany" or something similar.
Also agree with Baptiste on the usage of "best". Be careful, nowadays Google is pretty tough on overoptimisation.

Comment: Ok, good. Why is location so important? This company is international and not bound to a specific location. Can I remove location text in that case?

Comment: Yes - you can leave location out in this case, I just thought car repair would be local :) Usually it's important because you get targeted traffic, and you can rank higher for people searching for "Mazda car repair <cityname>" compared to "Mazda car repair".

Answer (score 0):

Depends if the company repair others brands, but let's say it doesn't, I would write an honest title, similar to what milo5b wrote :

```
SuperCompany - Japanese car repair service
```

I would probably add the location of the company if it has a clear service area (only one city, maybe one state).

I would never recommend you to use "Best" in the title, this kind of adjective is overused by spammy sites, and the company has probably not the *best* car repair service.

Comment: Baptiste, why is Toyota (and other brands) omitted? This company specialize strictly on those 4 brands. And they would like to emphasize this specialization (since other competitors provide more general list of brands - usually 15+ brands).

Comment: He omitted the others brands because it's borderline "keyword stuffing". Trying to squeeze too many keywords in a title tag just feels unnatural and doesn't usually help. I think Guisasso's suggestion is fairly reasonable though. But this is a valid concern and see where Baptiste is coming from. In either case, it would probably be good to have targeted landing pages for Honda repair service, Toyota repair service, etc.

Comment: This is a suggestion - the title is not everything and putting the 4 brands will make a long title. Google may even change it, he does it more and more. The brands will be on the page, put them in the meta description too. But most important part, create customized pages for every brand, they should all be different, because every car brand is different.

Comment: Yes, the landing pages for each brand will be there.

Answer (score 0):

HOME PAGE title and h1:

*CITY_NAME car repair service Toyota, Nissan, Mazda, Honda - COMPANY_NAME*

where CITY_NAME is the name of the city where the job shop is located.

Some INNER PAGES titles and h1s:

- "CITY_NAME car repair specialized in Toyota"
- "CITY_NAME car repair specialized in Nissan"
- ...